# problem-spring-webflux - NoSuchMethodError ResponseEntity.status

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, problem-spring

I'm using `spring boot 3`, `spring-webflux` and `problem-spring-webflux`.

I would like to catch `unauthorized` and `access denied` exceptions and return the relevant problem object. To do this I've added a `SecurityExceptionHandler` and included the configuration in a `SecurityConfiguration` class.

**SecurityExceptionHandler**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.general.ThrowableAdviceTrait;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.security.SecurityAdviceTrait;

@ControllerAdvice
public class SecurityExceptionHandler implements SecurityAdviceTrait, ThrowableAdviceTrait{}
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final SecurityProblemSupport securityProblemSupport;

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain webFluxSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(securityProblemSupport)
                .accessDeniedHandler(securityProblemSupport)
                .and()
                ...
                ...
                ...
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I access the service without a token a `NoSuchMethod` exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity$BodyBuilder org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.status(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus)'
    at org.zalando.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits.fallback(AdviceTraits.java:44) ~[problem-spring-common-0.27.0.jar:na]
    at org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.AdviceTrait.fallback(AdviceTrait.java:150) ~[problem-spring-webflux-0.27.0.jar:na]
    at org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.AdviceTrait.create(AdviceTrait.java:128) ~[problem-spring-webflux-0.27.0.jar:na]
    at org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.AdviceTrait.create(AdviceTrait.java:81) ~[problem-spring-webflux-0.27.0.jar:na]
    at org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.AdviceTrait.create(AdviceTrait.java:76) ~[problem-spring-webflux-0.27.0.jar:na]
    at org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.security.AuthenticationAdviceTrait.handleAuthentication(AuthenticationAdviceTrait.java:27) ~[problem-spring-webflux-0.27.0.jar:na]
    at org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport.commence(SecurityProblemSupport.java:32) ~[problem-spring-webflux-0.27.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.commenceAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.lambda$filter$2(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$29(Mono.java:3731) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:544) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2063) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2063) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4324) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.request(Operators.java:1906) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2158) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:77) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:91) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4324) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4324) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2400) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4324) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:465) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:109) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:269) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1817) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0-M2.jar:3.5.0-M2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

**gradle.build**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.example.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}


configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.springframework.boot', name : 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-route53', version: '1.12.212'
    implementation group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.15.0'
    implementation group: 'net.jodah', name: 'failsafe', version: '2.4.4'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.17.2'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '23.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.liquibase', name: 'liquibase-core', version: '4.10.0'
    implementation group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.30'
    implementation group: 'org.zalando', name: 'problem-spring-webflux', version: '0.27.0'
    runtimeOnly group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2'
    runtimeOnly group: 'io.r2dbc', name: 'r2dbc-h2'
    runtimeOnly group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql'
    runtimeOnly group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'r2dbc-postgresql'
    testAnnotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok'
    testImplementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    testImplementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-test'
    testImplementation group: 'jakarta.xml.bind', name: 'jakarta.xml.bind-api', version: '2.3.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I'm assuming this is dependency related but I have access to these classes/methods which leads me to believe it could be compatibility with `spring boot 3`.

What is causing this?

Comment: Spring Boot 3 isn't final yet and I doubt libraries like `problem-spring-webflux` or even the JWT libraries in use are ready for Spring Boot 3 and/or JakartaEE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make it work with the versions you have `problem-spring-webflux` relies on Spring 5.3 and spring boot 3 brings spring 6.
So you have a version mismatch and I guess it calls a method that exists in Spring 5 but not in 6